# Trying to block direct IP access with apache

Tags: apache, xampp

I'm using XAMPP on a Windows machine and I've added this code to the `httpd.conf` file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 23.23.23.23.23
    Redirect 403 /
    ErrorDocument 403 "No"
    DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs
    UseCanonicalName Off
    UserDir disabled
</VirtualHost>
```

I get this error when I try to restart apache:

```
11:15:02 AM  [Apache]   Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
11:15:02 AM  [Apache]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
11:15:02 AM  [Apache]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
11:15:02 AM  [Apache]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
11:15:02 AM  [Apache]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
11:15:02 AM  [Apache]   If you need more help, copy and post this
11:15:02 AM  [Apache]   entire log window on the forums
```

If I remove the code from the `httpd.conf` file it will start though. What's happening here?

Comment: Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `UserDir disabled` from config will solve your problem.